# Efficient methods for Incrementing and Decrementing in the same Loop

Tags: java, for-loop, increment, decrement

Suppose some situations exist where you would like to increment and decrement values in the same for loop.  In this set of situations, there are some cases where you can "cheat" this by taking advantage of the nature of the situation -- for example, reversing a string.

Because of the nature of building strings, we don't really have to manipulate the iterate or add an additional counter:

```
public static void stringReversal(){
    String str = "Banana";
    String forwardStr = new String();
    String backwardStr = new String();

    for(int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--){
        forwardStr = str.charAt(i)+forwardStr;
        backwardStr = backwardStr+str.charAt(i);
    }

    System.out.println("Forward String:  "+forwardStr);
    System.out.println("Backward String: "+backwardStr);   
}
```

However, suppose a different case exists where we just want to print a decremented value, from the initial value to 0, and an incremented value, from 0 to the initial value.

```
public static void incrementAndDecrement(){

   int counter = 0;

   for(int i = 10; i >= 0; i--){
       System.out.println(i);
       System.out.println(counter);
       counter++;
   } 
}
```

This works well enough, but having to create a second counter to increment seems messy.  Are there any mathematical tricks or tricks involving the for loop that could be used that would make `counter` redundant?

Comment: What's wrong with simple arithmetic? `10 - i`?

Comment: @JakeKing Sleep deprivation, I believe.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well it *looks* like you just want:

```
for(int i = 10; i >= 0; i--){
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(10 - i);
}
```

Is that the case? Personally I'd normally write this as an *increasing* loop, as I find it easier to think about that:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(10 - i);
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Note that your string example is *really* inefficient, by the way - far more so than introducing an extra variable. Given that you know the lengths involved to start with, you can just start with two `char[]` of the right size, and populate the right index each time. Then create a string from each afterwards. Again, I'd do this with an *increasing* loop:

```
char[] forwardChars = new char[str.length()];
char[] reverseChars = new char[str.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    forwardChars[i] = str.charAt(i);
    reverseChars[reverseChars.length - i - 1] = str.charAt(i);
}
String forwardString = new String(forwardChars);
String reverseString = new String(reverseChars);
```

(Of course `forwardString` will just be equal to `str` in this case anyway...)

Comment: and now the upvoting starts!! ;-)

Comment: I was actually hoping this would get a discussion started about efficiency in these sorts of problems, but I wasn't sure how to work that into the question.  Thanks for taking the extra step to elaborate on both examples!

Answer (score 7):

You can have multiple variables and incrementers in a `for` loop.

```
for(int i = 10, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(j);
}
```

Comment: how is that different from adding a counter variable?...the question is to reduce the number of variables.

Comment: It's not. He just requested it to be less "messy" and involving the for loop, so I figured this might be what he is looking for. :)

Comment: +1 for expanding my knowledge on the topic.  It is indeed less "messy" as it keeps everything in the loop, and as such is within the bounds of my question.